# Java Cast class object to superclass

Tags: java

So I got a method to get all classes in a package, and I have a way to testing if a class is extended to a speciel class

```
   for (Class c : classes) {
            System.out.println("Class: " + c);
            if (c.getSuperclass().equals(SpecielClass.class)) {
                System.out.println(c + " is SpecielClass");
            }
        }
```

but now, how do I get the "SpecielClass" methods from the c. If this is even possible?

Comment: When I try to do that it gives an error "Cannot cast from Class to SpecielClass"

Comment: Ow, forget what I said. You have _classes_ in there, not object instances. You need to create an instance from the class you're interested in; that's the only way to have access to its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `SpecielClass` methods from the `SpecielClass.class` object.

(since every instance of `c` is a `SpecielClass`, you can `invoke` these methods on an instance of `c`).

It also worth noting that `c.getMethods()` will include methods inherited from a super class (regardless of whether they are overridden in the subclass), while `c.getDeclaredMethods()` will only get methods declared in class `c`, but not those inherited from super types.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks, man, so I am new to the Class object, but I think I figured it out.